# Cannot Figure Out Why Audio File Is Not Playing (Java)

Tags: java, file, audio, wav

Kind of a noob to coding, but I've been creating Pacman for a computer science class, and for some reason, I cannot get my audio to work.

Basically, here is the just of what I have written.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    PlayAudio();
    //.... a lot of other stuff
}
```

My PlayAudio method:

```
public void PlayAudio()
{ 
    try 
    {
        Clip clickClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        File filePath = new File("opening.wav");
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(filePath);
        clickClip.open(ais);
        clickClip.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It compile and executes, but the audio file does not play. Thanks for the help!

I have confirmed that my opening.wav:

1. Is a `.wav` file.
2. Has the right name.
3. Is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 include new classes to play audio. Media and MediaPlayer. Example:

```
String media = "media.mp3";
Media hit = new Media(media);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

you need this libreries :

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
```